# View /Fetch logged user data when logged in - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is my data are being fetched at once, all of them. I need to view each user's data when Im on different logged in user. For example: For `user1` I need to have `Product1` and `user2` I need to have `Product2` but right now all Im getting is I can fetch all user's data.

here is my **Model**

> As you can see I added my join query but still fetching all my data

```
public function showAllReviewers(){
   $this->db->join('teachers', 'teachers.id = reviewers.user_id');
   $query = $this->db->get('reviewers');
      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
      }else{
        return false;
      }
}
```

My **Controller**

```
public function showAllReviewers()
{
    $result = $this->reviewer_model->showAllReviewers();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

My **View**

```
  <tbody id="showdata">

  </tbody>
```

I'm using ajax/js to fetch my data so here is my ajax/js script for additional info

```
    //function
    function showAllReviewers(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>reviewers/showAllReviewers',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html +='<tr class="table-info">'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].subject+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].category+'</td>'+
              '<td>'+data[i].set_rev+'</td>'+
              '<td>'+data[i].group_name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'"> <span class="iconify" data-icon="bx:bx-edit" data-inline="false"></span> </a> '+
                                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'"> <span class="iconify" data-icon="bx:bx-trash" data-inline="false"></span> </a>'+
                                '</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#showdata').html(html);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not get Data from Database');
            }
        });
    }
```

> EDIT: Login Controller

```
 // Log in teacher
  public function login(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'Code', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('teachers/login');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {

        // Get code
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        // Get and encrypt the password
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        // Login user
        $user = $this->teacher_model->login($code, $password);

        if($user){
            // Create session
            $user_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'code' => $code,
                'logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

            redirect('teacher/home');
        } else {
            redirect('teachers/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Im on different logged in user* ok, have you an ID of this user somewhere in PHP? You can catch it and pass into model for retrieving data only about this logged user. And you won't need to change anything in HTML or JS.

Comment: @Aksen P - Not that I know of, I dont have actually. I use session to retrieve names but that it is.

Comment: @AksenP - I'll edit my code and add my log in controller

Comment: Yes, sure, I hope you can get data about this username from DB after

Comment: @AksenP - there it is sir, I have added my login controller please see my edit code above, I did get my username from DB actually, but I cannot display my logged in user data that will match the `reviewers` user_id data

Comment: Look at @vivek_23 answer. He've get my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can store user data like `id` etc in session when user logs in, like below in your controller:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_details', $user_data); // say user_details is the key we store it in
```

In your model, you can do like below:

```
<?php


public function showAllReviewers(){
   $this->db->join('teachers', 'teachers.id = reviewers.user_id');
   $this->db->where('reviewers.user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_details')['user_id']);
   $query = $this->db->get('reviewers');
   if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
   }else{
    return false;
   }
}
```

Or an even better approach is to have a private variable say `user_id` and set the value in the constructor. This would make sure that whenever you are accessing model instance in your controller, you already have it in your model instead of retrieving from session always.

```
<?php

class YourModel extends CI_Model{
    private $user_id;

    function __construct(){
        $this->user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_details')['user_id'];
    }

    public function showAllReviewers(){
       $this->db->join('teachers', 'teachers.id = reviewers.user_id');
       $this->db->where('reviewers.user_id',$this->user_id);
       $query = $this->db->get('reviewers');
       if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
       }else{
        return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, I get your idea, 2nd option seems more approachable - I execute it then it says `Could not get data from database`

Comment: @SummerWinter Can you check with the SQL query that gets formed with `$this->db->get_compiled_select()` ?

Comment: @SummerWinter Or we can have simple select queries? More info https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: do you assume the problem is also in the query?

Comment: @SummerWinter Then you should be getting data from the database. Does raw SQL query execution give you any data? (like you can test the SQL in phpmyadmin)

Comment: yes sir, the query works on phpmyadmin, I wonder why it is not working on my code in CI - what is the `$this->session->set_userdata('user_details', $user_data);` **user_details** ? I wont changed it on my code right? it is just like a key u said?

Comment: I wont change anything on my `View` or `Controller` ?

Comment: @SummerWinter  You aren't getting any result because `var_dump($this->user_id)`  isn't giving you an ID. Yes, you have to add the first line of code in my answer in your controller when you login the user. `$user_data` is supposed to be a simple PHP array which has user related data like id,email etc.

Comment: @SummerWinter A small change with that as well. I have changed `'id'` to `'user_id'` since you have `user_id` in your array.

Comment: hey, we got the same problem haha, I also changed it then you answered it sir. thanks it works!

Comment: @SummerWinter Glad I cold help :)

Answer (score 1):

You must add a where condition in showAllReviewers() function's Sql query by passing current logged in User/Teacher Id Or in case of CI you can fetch the same using isLogged/getId function which used to be present in system/library/customer.